# C# SqlConnection can't connect

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sqlconnection

I want to connect to an online SQL database. to do that, I use this code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=77.243.225.193;User ID=rune;Password=secret;database=test");
conn.Open();
Textbox.Text = "ServerVersion: " + conn.ServerVersion.ToString() + "\n\r";
Textbox.Text = "State: " + conn.State.ToString();
```

I just got the code from the internet, since this is my first time using this.
Somehow this does not work because it says that it can't connect to the database. Can anyone explain me why?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, for starters, are you sure the database is running?

Comment: Yea, check everything, ip, username, etc.  Can you ping the db from your location?

Comment: Your code looks right. Just make sure the IP address is correct, the database is, in fact, SQL Server, and the username and password are correct. Also make sure the database allows for remote connections and that your firewall is not blocking the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run throug a series of tests and check off the ones that past:

1. Is 77.243.255.139 a valid address? Can you ping it?
2. Does the Sql Server @ the IP address require a connection on a specific port, e.g. 77.243.255.139,1724?
3. Is `test` a valid name of a database that is online and mounted on the server?
4. Is `rune` a valid SQL login for the server?
5. Does `rune` have the appropriate permissions to access the `test` database?
6. Is the password correct?

There are obviously a myriad of reasons why you might not be able to connect, what exact error message are you getting?

*UPDATE*: based on your last comment, you saying you use phpMyAdmin... Which is a management tool for MySql databases (someone correct me if I am wrong)?

If it is a MySql database, you need to be using MySql ADO.NET Connector along with a valid MySql connection string. Check http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: It's a valid IP.. I noticed that its *.*.225.* instead of 255, but it didnt change a thing. I don't know if it runs on a specific port, it's not my server. It does use phpMyAdmin, dunno if that makes a difference. The rest is correct and from within phpMyAdmin I can check and edit the database.

Comment: The connector looks good, and i found a guide on how to use the connector. Now it says i need do add reference to: MySql.Data, but I can't seem find MySql.Data.. and yes, I did install the connector..

Comment: MySql.Data will likely be installed somewhere like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.NET 5.0.3\Driver\bin\net-2.0\release\MySql.Data.dll`. I'd recommend you add a reference, but then change the `Copy Local` property to `true` in the properties pane.

Comment: I now get the error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." immediately, so the connection is right, it just doesn't allow it probably. Thanks alot for this info, now I'm going to slap my host again ;) using this piece of code now: `string MyConString = "SERVER=77.243.225.193,1433;" +
                "DATABASE=test;" +
                "UID=rune;" +
                "PASSWORD=secret;";` and the rest from this guide: [link](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html)

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server Express (or Developer edition) then I assume remote connections using TCP/IP isn't enabled (that's the default). If you have access to the SQL Server then I suggestion you follow the instructions in this link: [Configure SQL Server for remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277). You can also try to telnet to port 1433 (default SQL Server port), using "telnet 77.243.255.139 1433" from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Data Source=77.243.225.193,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=test;
User ID=rune;Password=secret;
```

The

```
Network Library=DBMSSOCN
```

tells the provider to use TCP/IP instead of named pipes.

I notice from your previous comment, that there's some confusion over the IP address and I've assumed that it's 77.243.225.193, but *please* find out the definitive address; you'll get nowhere if you don't!

Comment: Nice to know about the Network Library, but that didn't work either. I contacted the server owner about this, lets hope he didn't forget to allow remote connections.. he told me before that it should work but you never know.. and the 225 IP is the correct one. i'll edit the question.